# Find items only present once in a list

Tags: c#

I have a variable of type `List<int>` and I am trying to find items which are **unique** in the list – i.e. they only appear once.

Sample: `var data = new List<int>{1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 7}();`
Expected output : `5,7`

Comment: Sample :
var data = new List<int> () { 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 7 };

Answer (score 3):

Just group and then select where the count is `1`:

```
var uniqueList = data.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this LINQ Statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 1, 5, 2, 2 , 7 });
        var output = data.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
                                .Where(a => data.Count(b => a.value == b) == 1)
                                .Select(a => a.value)
                                .ToList();

        output.ForEach(o => System.Console.WriteLine(o));
    }
}
```

If you're still looking for the indexes, you might want to try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 1, 5, 2, 2 , 7 });
        var output = data.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
                                .Where(a => data.Count(b => a.value == b) == 1)
                                .Select(a => a.index)
                                .ToList();

        output.ForEach(o => System.Console.WriteLine(o));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this has a quadratic runtime since it will enumerate the list (to count) for every single item.

Comment: I totally agree with this @poke

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq as well,

```
var listA = new List<int> {1, 1, 5, 2, 2 , 7};
var listB = from g in listA.GroupBy(x => x)  where g.Count() == 1  select g.First();
foreach (var item in listB)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**[`DOTNET FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cms2Pq)**